# Using HTML Imports with Cordova

Tags: cordova

Running the app in the ios emulator and it's not picking up any of the style sheets. If I remove the styles from the imported file it works fine, but I would like to keep them there since I also use HTML templates. I added the webcomponents.js polyfill just in case and it still does not work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/includes/head.html">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that html imports with the webcomponents pollyfill works on phonegap.

Your problem should be solved using a relative url instead of an absolute one for your import:

```
<link rel="import" href="includes/head.html">
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is the css files should also be referenced with a relative url.